# How can I use a preprocessor in Rust to detect the version number?

Tags: rust

In C, I can do

```c
#if GCC_VERSION > 5
    ...
#else
    ...
#endif
```

How to do this in Rust?

I want to write portable code that uses `BTreeMap::append()` if Rust is at least 1.11 and use something else otherwise.

Comment: Take a look at [the chapter on conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/conditional-compilation.html). I'm not sure it can use the compiler version as a condition, though.

Comment: The 'proper' solution, as far as I know, is to say 'requires Rust >= 1.11'; there is very little use in keeping old versions around because backwards compatibility is never broken (but forwards compatibility is not guaranteed).

Comment: A tip: Your title is asking a different question than the body, don't do that :D